# Substitute scipy.spatial.distance

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to write a python code to be used on a raspberrypi, I then would like to not have to install the scipy library but on the other way I would like to exploit the * scipy.spatial.distance* class, in particular the *cdist* function.

I would use this function to evaluate the distance between each pair of object centroids and input centroids:

```
d = dist.cdist (objectCentroids, inputCentroids)
```

Any idea on what I could do to not install scipy? Does someone has already written another, maybe lighter library to perform that operation or a standalone function? Or I should simply use numpy?

```
d = np.sqrt(np.sum((objectCentroids - inputCentroids)**2,axis=1))
```

Thanks for any advice

Matteo